# Defining multiple matrices in a loop

Tags: python-2.7, loops, for-loop, matrix

I would like to create a set of matrix(all 3 X 3), B*ij* (like B11, B12, B13, B21, B22, B23, B31, B32, B33 all are all 3 X 3) with 1 at *ij* th entry and 0 everywhere else. For eg.

```
B_12 = [[0,1,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]
```

and

```
B_23 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,0,1],
        [0,0,0]]
```

I tried with the following code

```
for z in range(9):
    B = [[0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if i==j:
                val = 1
            else:
                val = 0
            B[i][j] = val
    print B
```

But it is not giving the desirable matrix. 
Could anybody suggest me the correct logic?

Thanks

Comment: Is the rank of the matrix always supposed to be 3 X 3 ?

Comment: yes always supposed to be 3 by 3 matrix

Answer (score 0):

If I am able to understand your question correctly, what you are looking for is the code to modify the value of an index in the matrix and this is pretty simple.

```
B = [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ]
B[i][j] = 1 # This is your B_ij
```

I don't think you need loops here.
If you are looking for something else, kindly rephrase the question properly.